# Rooted Android Emulator

Tags: google-play-store, root-access, google, android-emulator, avd-manager

I want to install avd with google play and work with it as a root, is it possible?
if not there any chance to install google play on rooted  android emulator , because I have an app the I can't install not via the google play store.
Thanks

Comment: You don't need to root a device to install an APK not available in Google PlayStore. Just install it via `adb install` (requires Android SDK/ADB minimal installed on the PC and `adb` enabled on the device which is by default enabled on emulators).

Comment: I need the root for the next steps (reverse engineering ) and I need that app installed.the problem is that I can't find that apk on the web, so the solution is to install it with google play but then I don't have rooted device ...

Comment: If the app itself does not need Google Play Services I would not use an emulator with Google Play installed. APK files can be extracted from non-rooted devices as well. Several file explorer apps have this functionality and via `adb` you can do it yourself. Also Web services like apkpure.com can download the APK file for you or you use a local download tool like https://raccoon.onyxbits.de BTW: If you are non-commercial you can simply use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone/) emulators, they are already rooted and free for private use.

Comment: I have tried all those methods but nothing works, in apkpure I found XAPK and I cant install it...:(

Comment: Install XAPK: https://apkpure.com/xapk.html

Comment: Thanks , it doesn't work also, this is arm64 app , any other idea ? I don't know what its so complicated .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110870/discussion-between-elior-and-robert).

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44473415/191761